# Why do I receive notifications of lowmen prunes even though half the query cache is not being used?

Tags: mysql, sql, caching

I'm using a monitoring system that has been reporting every few hours that there were a lot of lowmem prunes

Thu Dec 5 01:21:52 UTC 2013
7347 query cache lowmem prunes in 600 seconds (12.24/sec)

Thu Dec 5 10:21:52 UTC 2013
10596 query cache lowmem prunes in 600 seconds (17.66/sec)

Thu Dec 5 11:26:52 UTC 2013
8979 query cache lowmem prunes in 600 seconds (14.96/sec)

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qc%';
Variable_name            Value
Qcache_free_blocks       2250
Qcache_free_memory       6938840
Qcache_hits              578811080
Qcache_inserts           331501709
Qcache_lowmem_prunes     124066063
Qcache_not_cached        135977294
Qcache_queries_in_cache  5638
Qcache_total_blocks      13625
```

About 6MB of my 16MB query cache is not being used

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size';
+------------------+----------+
| Variable_name    | Value    |
+------------------+----------+
| query_cache_size | 16777216 |
+------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why are queries being pruned without the cache filling up?

Should I increase or decrease my cache size?

**Additional information**

```
mysql> FLUSH STATUS;
```

30 minutes later

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE '%Qcache%';
+-------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name           | Value   |
+-------------------------+---------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 1935    |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 5154904 |
| Qcache_hits             | 43918   |
| Qcache_inserts          | 33074   |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 4443    |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 10438   |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 6276    |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 14713   |
+-------------------------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query cache expires entries when any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements modify data in the associated table. This does not wait for the cache to fill up.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-operation.html says:

> If a table changes, all cached queries that use the table become invalid and are removed from the cache. This includes queries that use MERGE tables that map to the changed table. A table can be changed by many types of statements, such as INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE, or DROP DATABASE.

---

Re your question:

> If using InnoDB and the insertion is at the end of a table, does the query cache expire entries?

Yes, that's correct. Say for example a query cache entry is associated with a query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable`. An insert to the end of `mytable` would make the cached result from this query invalid.

The query cache doesn't have much intelligence with respect to deciding whether a given change to the data affects the cached entry. It assumes that if you change *anything* in a table, then all queries in the cache associated with that table in any way must be discarded.

It could apply more intelligence to discard some query results only if the cached result would change after your insert. But how would it do that? It would have to run the query again after your insert, comparing the result to the result that is stored in the cache. If they differ, replace the result in the cache.

But it would have to do that with *every* query result in the cache. Note that your status output shows your query cache has 5638 queries in it. Of course not every one of these is associated with the same table you're inserting into, but we can assume that many of them are.

It would not be a good tradeoff for a single INSERT to cause hundreds or thousands of SELECT statements to be re-executed to refresh their cached results.

So the compromise is that a change to a table purges *all* cached results associated with that table, even if it was not strictly necessary.

---

The query cache is therefore not a very precise method for caching queries. It can be helpful for certain workloads, for example if your application tends to repeat a given uery many times while the table receives no changes. But [we](http://percona.com) have seen many cases where the workload makes the query cache not helpful, and in some cases the overhead of maintaining the query cache is actually a detriment to performance.

If you want some cache mechanism that is more precise, you have to code it yourself in your application, saving certain results to memcached or similar fast in-memory cache. Then it becomes your responsibility to track which entries need to be refreshed when data changes.

Comment: If using InnoDB and the insertion is at the end of a table, does the query cache expire entries?